# How to update the Jquery UI to v1.13.0 in wso2 identity server 6.0.0?

Tags: jquery-ui, wso2, wso2-identity-server

currently jquery.ui.core.min.js is pointing to version 1.10.4.
I tried updating with jQueryBump , Carbon-kernel from github. But still /carbon/admin/js/jquery.ui.core.min.js  is pointing to older version.

I need jQueryUI v1.13.0 to my wso2 identity server 6.0.0

Comment: Where did you make the change in carbon-kernel?